# Git: не отделяется ветка от основной dev, что смотреть, как исправить?

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitlab

Уже всю голову сломал...

Работаю через phpstorm и консолью почти не пользуюсь.
Есть две основные ветки на gitlab, это master и dev.

Пример: я создаю новую ветку от dev, к примеру feature/test. Далее делаю изменения в один или несколько коммитов. Сливаю в свою ветку в dev с помощью Merge into current (находясь на ветке dev), шторм пишет типа все ок - все слито. Но тут уже проблема т.к. по логу в VC он показывает коммиты в самой ветке dev как будто я не создавал новую ветку. Естественно это все приходилось сливать в master.
И важно то что при операции merge branch никакого коммита типа "Merge branch feature/test into dev" нету.
Настройки все проверил все дефолтное как после установки git.

**Ошибок никаких не появляется, конфликтов тоже нет.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял.

При слияние веток, вы должны использовать атрибут `git`-да `--no-ff`.
[image: git merge --no-ff]

> **На данный момент, у PHPStorma нет такой настройки**

Смотрим сюда [issue-IDEA-99115](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99115)

В комментах на их трекере было предложено следующее решение:

`git config --global --add merge.ff false`

попробуйте возможно оно сработает, если да, можно будет это в `global` конфиг перенести

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде сработало. Появились коммиты с мержем в dev. Но появились новые вопросы. Откуда и зачем это появилось? "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/dev' into dev" И второй вопрос как перенести настройку merge.ff false в global конфиг?

Comment: @МаксимМезенцев насчет первого нечего не скажу, насчет второго, попробуйте `git config --global --edit`